# Precision of sklearn.metric classification_report

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I would like to know if it is possible to get more numbers after the comma with classification_report from sklearn (scikit).

atm it looks like this:

```
         precision    recall  f1-score   support

      1       0.61      0.73      0.67     71194
      2       0.64      0.33      0.43     13877
      3       0.56      0.59      0.57     61591
      4       0.64      0.51      0.57     13187
      5       0.66      0.69      0.67     57530
      6       0.54      0.06      0.11      2391
      7       0.54      0.40      0.46     30223
```

avg / total       0.60      0.60      0.60    249993

I don't think it is possible with that method, but maybe someone had the same idea (probably).

I know that `sklearn.metrics.precision_score` exists, though the classification_report is such a nice way to display all the results at once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not possible according to the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/metrics/metrics.py). See lines 819 and 830, format strings are hardcoded to `%0.2f`. If you really want it, just change it in your local file `sklearn/metrics/metrics.py`. Better yet, add an argument to `classification_report` with a precision number and use that. And submit your patch to the project!